# Getting all system-level icons

Tags: front-end, undocumented, elided-forms

`Dispatch` and `InterpolatingFunction` have these fun little icons on their summary boxes. How can I find the list of those?

Answer (score 6):

These are stored in `` BoxForm`GenericIcon `` and you can see the entire list as a `Dataset` like:

```
Dataset@
 Replace[
  DownValues@BoxForm`GenericIcon, 
  (Verbatim[HoldPattern][HoldPattern[BoxForm`GenericIcon[ob_]]] :> 
     icon_) :>
   <|
    "Object" -> ob,
    "Icon" -> icon
    |>,
  1
  ]
```

One stellar example of graphic design is the icon for `` Region`SemialgebraicRegion ``:

[image: sdfasd]

Comment: To be fair, the stellar icon is [based](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/ImplicitRegion.en/O_16.png) on an actual [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/ImplicitRegion.en/I_40.png).

Comment: @ilian stellar is good :) I figured there was some basis for it. I just also found it amusing.